# How image are handle by the browser and how to save them without reloading?

Tags: caching, browser, cache-control

Just to be sure, if you load a page and let's say this page has 3 images. First refere to "/images/1.jpgn", the second to "/images/2.jpg" and the third to "/images/1.jpg" again. When the page sent to the browser, will the browser make a new request to the server and ask for the image? And if the image has already been request (like my "lets say", it has two time the same image) will it request it again or it will know that this image/url has already been loaded and will just retrieve it from the temp?

Which lead to my second question, is there a way to save with javascript/jquery this image on the computer (with the download box opening like if you were downloading a file) from the temp without having to request it again from the server?

I don't know if I am really clear but in short, I want to save an image of the page from the cache and not request a download to the server.

Comment: Why do you want to do this and NOT allow the normal cache mechanism to do this for you?

Comment: It's because my image is sent by a php file that run so verification to allow you to see the image and I wanted to be sure it won't run these verifications when they have already been made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers generally cache what they can, according to what the HTTP response headers say. That is, servers ultimately control what browsers can (or should) cache, so it's server configuration that usually controls such things.

This applies not only to images but all content: HTML pages, CSS, JavaScript, etc.

Comment: nice thanks exactly what I wanted to know. Wasn't sure if it is for all content type.

Answer (score 2):

It is all on how the server sends the image the 1st time (with or without caching).

If you have caching enabled on your browser, the browser will usually check your cache **before** requesting the file from the server.

Comment: even if the image is sent by a php file?

Comment: yeah of course =D wanted to be sure it didn't depend of the requested ressource's type.

Answer (score 1):

The browser should take care of. It won't continually re-request the same file.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, the browser will see that two images have the same source and therefore only download it once.

However if the same image is requested again later, the browser will send an `If-Not-Modified-Since` header to the server. The server can then respond with `304 Not Modified`, at which point the browser uses the local copy to "download instantly".